# Floating row in Numbers for iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, numbers

Is there a way I can make a row float on top of everything else. So, no matter how many rows you add, the row will always be visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make the header row(s) or column(s) float on top of everything else.

Tap the information button (the circled i) in the toolbar at the top of the screen. Under the "Headers" tab, select how many header rows or columns you would like, and set "Freeze Rows" to ON.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Is there any way to make a row in the middle of the page floating?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there is not.